# Removing Leading Space

Tags: spacing, align

I would like to remove the leading space that appears on the left before the equation on the latex below.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\large
\begin{align*}
&{\bf y}_{l} = \sum _{k=1}^{L} {\bf H}_{l,k} {\bf x}_{k}+ {\bf w}_{l} &{{(1)}}
\end{align*}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cant post a comment yet so I am giving an answer instead.

If you want to left align the equation, you can use

```
\begin{flalign*}
&{\bf y}_{l} = \sum _{k=1}^{L} {\bf H}_{l,k} {\bf x}_{k}+ {\bf w}_{l} &{{(1)}}
\end{flalign*}
```

if that's what you mean by "remove the leading space".