# Empty space in standalone document with textopo

Tags: spacing, standalone

The question is related to similar issues with standalone package: lots of empty space is added in addition to the desired figure. However, this time no empty paragraphs in source code. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textopo}
\begin{document}
\begin{textopo}
\sequence{EIKKKLFWRAV[VAEFLAMTLFVFISIGSA]LGFNYPLERN}
\end{textopo}
\end{document}
```

Produces following png after running `pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode mwe.tex`

[image: apparently too wide output]

I suspect that the problem is in textopo package rather than standalone, however, I need confirmation from someone more experienced. And any workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this  is the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115342/how-to-remove-the-unwanted-space-on-the-left-side-of-the-following-gather  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65193/removing-leading-space  these constructs center the construction "by hand" and it works in a normal class but defeats standalone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use `article` and then crop externally eg using `pdfcrop`  using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textopo}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{textopo}
\sequence{EIKKKLFWRAV[VAEFLAMTLFVFISIGSA]LGFNYPLERN}
\end{textopo}
\end{document}
```

followed by applying `pdfcrop` (as installed with texlive 2012) produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this combo seems like reasonable replacement for `standalone` class

Answer (score 3):

If I build the `textopo` environment in a box, the computed width is 5178.32596pt, which is 6 feet or 1.8 meters.

You get a more reasonable output if you use the `varwidth` option to `standalone`. There's still white space at the sides, though.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{textopo}
\begin{document}
\begin{textopo}
\sequence{EIKKKLFWRAV[VAEFLAMTLFVFISIGSA]LGFNYPLERN}
\end{textopo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, egreg. Yes, varwidth works fine with MWE. However, my real need includes much longer `sequence` argument and the output doesn't fit to the `linewidth` anymore. So eventually I'll need to manually adjust document width - exactly what I was trying to avoid using `standalone` class :)

Comment: @user28683 `[preview,convert]` give the same output like above. Note: "Tikz pstricks ...picture and similar environments are the
main target of the standalone class".`pdfcrop` is another way.